# How to load an embedded resource from a base class that is in another VS project from that base class

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, xsd, resources

Trying to embed an XSD in a base class assembly that is used by multiple derived class assemblies.

Visual Studio 2013 project A:

```
namespace A.B.C
{
    public abstract class WidgetBase {
        protected virtual void LoadSchema() {
            var schemas = new XmlSchemaSet();

            using (var resourceStream = this.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("A.B.C.Schemas.SchemaA.xsd"))
            {
               ...Load the schema...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In csproj 2 I have a class that uses that base class:

Visual Stdio 2013 project B

```
namespace D.E 
{
    public class WidgetDerived : WidgetBase {
        public string DoSomethingWithXml(string xmlFile)
        {
            var schema = base.LoadSchema();
            ...do something...
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that I cannot find the XSD in object browser or setting the resource path to:

```
var resourceStream = this.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("A.B.C.Schemas.SchemaA.xsd")
var resourceStream = typeof(WidgetBase).Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("A.B.C.Schemas.SchemaA.xsd")
var resourceStream = typeof(WidgetBase).Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("D.E.Schemas.SchemaA.xsd")
```

The code runs fine if I load the XSD from a relative disk path. As an embedded resource though I'm not quite sure where it's going.  I would think it would be embedded in the base class assembly and therefore visible to itself.

I've seen other answers for using GetManifestResourceStream when the resource is in another assembly and in the same assembly (here and https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/319292 and many others) but not when the base class is loading its own assembly after a call from a derived class.  In theory it should be the exact same as when loading from self, but it's not working that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crud.  The thing I tried first, but had a typo:

```
var resourceStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("A.B.C.Schemas.FuzzyTestPlan.xsd")
```

So, FYI, it does use the namespace and path of the relative assembly to the code.  Just have to make sure you type it out correctly.  :s